# Looking for word processor/plugin to machine translate selected text segments

Tags: translation, plug-in, word-processor

I'm basically looking to translate language text embedded in source code. It's about 16.000 lines and 2mil symbols(japanese), so it's a bit of an undertaking.

It should be machine translated, the accuarcy doesn't matter too much, however, I can't just upload it to google and have it translated, because each line is numbered, and the document is full of markup language for line breaks, embedded images and such, which need to remain untouched, and google usually makes a mess of it and moves the tags around, ignores tabs etc.

I've found a plugin for Notepad++ but it no longer works (npptranslate on sourceforge). It seemed to do what I need: highlight a text fragment in a document, press a hotkey and have it translated right within the document.

I need a word processor/plugin which can do the same, translate highlighted text from one language to another on key press. No pop-up or opening of tabs to show the translation, just replace the selected text.

Please advise.

Comment: can you not just rollback to an older version of Notepad++ / the plug-in ?

Comment: Sadly, no, I've tried that to see the plugin in action, but the APIs for online translation the plugin uses are deprecated and no longer accessible.

Comment: If  it's FOSS, can you fork it?

Comment: Good point, I just grabbed the source, it's in C# which I have no experience in, but I'm not too shy to try.

Comment: That's the spirit!  Wish I could upvote more :-)  If you expand it, I hope that you will FOSS the result.  You might also ask here for a C# to <your preferred language> translator (unlikely to be 100%, but better than nothing). Good luck